# Table content independent in each row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button to add new rows to a table, and my issue is the ng-model value. Its target when an option is selected from an dropdown, to show all data from that item in the other fields, and when a new row is created, all the ng-model have the same value.If you pick 2 times the same device and add a value, it update in both and need to just to update in one of them.

Here's the example of the current state of the code with a working example http://jsfiddle.net/z06sonnt/5/

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" id="midi-ctrl">
<button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td><strong>{{row.id}}</strong>
    </td>
    <td align="center">{{row.selectedItem.type}}</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select ng-model="row.selectedItem" ng-options="item.product for item in products">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>{{row.selectedItem.price}} </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input style="width: 75px" ng-model="row.selectedItem.quantity" ng-change="calcPrice(row.selectedItem)" type='number'>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input style="width: 75px" ng-model="row.selectedItem.notes">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input style="width: 75px" ng-model="row.selectedItem.cost">$
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<b>rows</b>{{rows}}
<br>
<b>Products</b>{{products}}
```

Controller.js

```
  function Ctrl($scope) {
 $scope.rows = [{
id: '1',
selectedItem: []
}, {
id: '2',
selectedItem: []
}];
$scope.counter = 3;

$scope.calcPrice = function(item) {
item.cost = item.price * item.quantity;
};

$scope.addRow = function() {
$scope.newRow = {};
$scope.newRow['id'] = $scope.counter;
$scope.newRow['selectedItem'] = [];
$scope.rows.push($scope.newRow);
$scope.counter++;
};

$scope.products = [{
type: 'mobile',
product: 'Device A',
price: 70
}, {
type: 'games',
product: 'Device B',
price: 80
}, {
type: 'PC',
product: 'Device C',
price: 100
}, ];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided a plunkr or codepen example of this code.

Comment: @gaurav5430 the `selectedItem` fields to belong each row like the answer they added here

Comment: @SeanLarkin Ive Added a jsfiddle with the current state of my code

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your selected item an object within your rowContent. Something like this

```
<div class="col-lg-12" >
<button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<table class="table table-bordered ">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Software Cost</th>
        <th>Labor</th>
        <th>Workflow</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td align="center">{{row.id }}{{row.selectedItem.clientType}}</td>
        <td align="center"><select ng-model="row.selectedItem"
                                   ng-options="item.software for item in products">
            <option value="">Select Client</option>
        </select></td>
        <td align="center"><input ng-model="row.selectedItem.quantity" ng-change="calcLabor(row.selectedItem)"></td>
        <td align="center"><input ng-model="row.selectedItem.locations" ng-change="calcLabor(row.selectedItem)"></td>
        <td align="center"><input ng-model="row.selectedItem.notes"></td>
        <td align="center">{{(row.selectedItem.price)*(row.selectedItem.quantity)|currency}}</td>
        <td align="center"><input ng-model="row.selectedItem.labor">
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#image-modal">
                <button ng-click="imageShowModal(row.selectedItem)">Edit Formula</button>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><input ng-model="row.selectedItem.workflow"></td>
        <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("appController", ["$scope", "$filter", function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.rows=[{ id:'1', selectedItem:[] }, { id:'2', selectedItem:[] }];
    $scope.counter=3;
    $scope.imageShowModal = function (item) {
    $scope.bedModal = item;
};

$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.newRow = {};
    $scope.newRow['id'] = $scope.counter;
    $scope.newRow['selectedItem'] = [];
    $scope.rows.push($scope.newRow);
    $scope.counter++;
};
```

Comment: I had tried that way, but the error is: 
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selectedItem' of 1
    at fn.assign (eval at <anonymous>

Comment: I think you need to declare each selectedItem within the row in your controller. something like $scope.row = [{ id:'1', selectedItem:[ ] }]

Comment: I modified the answer above to add the object to the controller

Comment: Now doesnt generate error, but i have the same problem, if insert same products it changes in both products, and they should be independent, i guess the problem is in the selectedItem array, that contains the json with the information.

Comment: I would assume it has something to do with your selectedItem array. This should be working. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fa2Sw/11/)

Comment: Ive updated your example showing my problem, ive added a field, and if i select the same device and add a value on the text input, he writes in both [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/fa2Sw/14/). question has been also updated